# How to sum the values of checked fields in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a grid which is displaying the data from **MYSQL** db in **PHP**

Also i have provided a checkbox, if the user checks the checkbox, checked values should be added and display in the bottom.

here is the php grid :

```
<form id='myform' method='post' action=''>
<table id='mytable'>
     <?php
       $sql_getData = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE";
       $result_getData = mysql_query();
       while($arr_data = mysql_fetch_array($sql_getData))
       {
             ?>
                 <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $arr_data['payment_id'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $arr_data['payments'] ?></td>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' name='mycheckbox' class='mycheckbox'></td>
                 <tr>
             <?php
       }
     ?>
     <tr><td>Total Payments</td><td>TOTAL_VALUE</td></tr>
     </table>
</form>
```

**Edit : PROVIDING OUTPUT AS SUGGESTED BY  Reigel ** 
**Expected output :** [image]

How do i display the TOTAL_VALUE using jquery

**Updated code which is adding all the values in the loop as it should not...! :**

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
    <table id="mytable">
        <?php
        $sql_getData = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE";
        $result_getData = mysql_query();
        while($arr_data = mysql_fetch_array($sql_getData)){
            echo '
             <tr>
                <td>'.$arr_data['payment_id'].'</td>
                <td>'.$arr_data['payments'].'</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" class="mycheckbox" data-payment="'.$arr_data['payments'].'"></td>
             <tr>'
           }
         ?>
         <tr>
            <td>Total Payments</td>
            <td id="tp">0.00</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</form>

<script>
$(".mycheckbox").change(function(){
    var payment = 0;
    $(".mycheckbox:checked").each(function(){
        payment += parseFloat($(this).attr("data-payment"));
    });
    $("#tp").html("<p>"+payment.toFixed(2)+"</p>");
});
</script>
```

**Final updated code which is working perfect as guided by Andy gee:**

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
    <table id="mytable">
        <?php
        $sql_getData = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE";
        $result_getData = mysql_query();
        while($arr_data = mysql_fetch_array($sql_getData)){
            echo '
             <tr>
                <td>'.$arr_data['payment_id'].'</td>
                <td>'.$arr_data['payments'].'</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" class="mycheckbox" data-payment="'.$arr_data['payments'].'"></td>
             <tr>'
           }
         ?>
         <tr>
            <td>Total Payments</td>
            <td id="tp">0.00</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</form>

<script>
$(".mycheckbox").change(function(){
    var payment = 0;
    $(".mycheckbox").each(function(){
        payment += $(this).prop("checked") ? parseFloat($(this).attr("data-payment")) : 0;
    });
    $("#tp").html("<p>"+payment.toFixed(2)+"</p>");
});
</script>
```

Comment: where did you applly jquery...????

Comment: i have not applied jquery. As im new bie to jquery. Please suggest how to acheive this.

Comment: shouldn't `$sql_getData = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE";
       $result_getData = mysql_query();
       while($arr_data = mysql_fetch_array($sql_getData))` be `$sql_getData = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE";
       $result_getData = mysql_query($sql_getData);
       while($arr_data = mysql_fetch_array($result_getData))` correct me if I'm wrong but for as far as I see your code is wrong with it and the fact that you still use mysql (which is depracted) and not mysqli

Comment: can you provide a sample output?

Comment: Please show HTML rather than PHP; the PHP is irrelevant once the server's sent the page to the browser. Incidentally, this is potentially moderately easy (with the caveat that it's only easy once you know jQuery/JavaScript): why haven't you tried anything yet? The [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) is *excellent* for learning the methods, and [learn.jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/) is good for guiding people new to the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly this should do that for you - assuming `$arr_data['payments']` contains the payment amount

```
<?
$exch_rate = 1.2;
?>


<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
    <table id="mytable">
        <?php
        $sql_getData = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE";
        $result_getData = mysql_query();
        while($arr_data = mysql_fetch_array($sql_getData)){
            echo '
             <tr>
                <td>'.$arr_data['payment_id'].'</td>
                <td>'.$arr_data['payments'].'</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" class="mycheckbox" data-payment="'.$arr_data['payments'].'"></td>
             <tr>'
           }
         ?>
         <tr>
            <td>Total Payments</td>
            <td id="tp">0.00</td>
            <td id="anotherid">0.00</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</form>

<script>
$(".mycheckbox").change(function(){
    var exch_rate = <?=$exch_rate;?>;
    var payment = 0;
    $(".mycheckbox").each(function(){
        payment += $(this).prop("checked") ? parseFloat($(this).attr("data-payment")) : 0;
    });
    $("#tp").html("<p>"+payment.toFixed(2)+"</p>");
    payment *= exch_rate;
    $("#anotherid").html("<p>"+payment.toFixed(2)+"</p>");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank youuu @andy exactly what i was looking for.. But when use your jquery it is displaying NaN on <td id="tp">0.00</td>

Comment: it is working fine now. Done little mistake while integrating, thanks for your help in achieving this

Comment: hey when im testing code it is summing up all the values in the loop just now identified. where it is wrng?

Comment: it fixed thanks again for the support im updating question with your answers

Comment: a small extension to the question.. Is it possible to show another <td id="anotherid">0.00</td> This value will be generated in Another currency. As in <td id="tp">0.00</td> we are displaying USD. i need to convert into some other currency, exchange rate will be in another td say <td id="anotherid">120</td>

Comment: Sure see the updated answer. I thought you might like to get the exchange rate from PHP so I included the php/js bridge too.